Can we theoretically calculate the value of r from which the logistic map starts doubling its period?
Consider the logistic map:
$$x_{n+1}=rx_{n}(1-x_{n})$$
We know that the generated values of $x$ after a certain number of iterations start to show chaotic behaviour instead of "settling" to particular values when $r$ goes above a certain value, for some sensible initial value of $x$, let's say one half.
Is there a way to find out the region of chaotic behaviour by merely looking at the function's properties (as opposed to iterating numerically to demonstrate this behaviour)? Can we look at a general function and make claims about its chaotic behaviour/lack thereof without checking it numerically?
Edit: I had this thought because I was playing around generating these maps for various tweaks in the given function, and a lot of seemingly "visually complex" functions (with a lot more $x$ terms multiplied) showed relatively stable behaviour compared to this particular function.

You can predict the values of $r$ for which the period will double. You get period $2$ for $r \in (3, 1+ \sqrt{6})$. Take a look at link
